# Magento, checkout/cart block not loading in ajax extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm programming an ajax extension to Magento and I'm having trouble when I try to make checkout/cart work with it.

I want to reload the entire block, including the item and also the cart totals after a change in any product in the cart.

I've modified the layout as many sites said and I can't get the checkout/cart block render well.

My two solutions were:

---

1° Tryed to update the layout via an xml file, and I get a false in $block_cart.

I've a class

```
Mati_Ajax_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
...
    public function updateShoppingCartAction()
    {
        ...
        $block_cart = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout/cart');
        ...
    }
}
```

and a xml file (which I'm sure i'ts being loaded beacause the js pointed there is loading)

```
<checkout_cart_updateshoppingcart>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_index" />
</checkout_cart_updateshoppingcart>
```

---

2° Tryed to create the block

```
public function updateShoppingCartAction()
{
    ...
    $block_cart = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('checkout/cart')->setTemplate("checkout/cart.phtml")->toHtml();
    ...
}
```

And here I get the block, but when the template executes `$this->getChildHtml('totals');` 
It gets a false anwer, so the webpage has some differences with the previousone

---

Does anybody knows how to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt just append `->toHtml();`

Alternatively you could have included that as a command in the xml `output="toHtml"`

Check how the `checkout/onepage/review` functions if you are looking for advice. 
There they access the response object and then set the body of the response to the html variable, in your case `$block_cart`

Comment: thank you for your answer! as I get a false, when I execute ->toHtml() to it, I get an error, that's why i didn't wrote it here.

Answer (score 0):

The key was in the xml file

```
<ajax_cart_updateshoppingcart>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_index" />
</ajax_cart_updateshoppingcart>
```